# Date comparison in Javascript acts like a string comparison

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular and have the following filter function in my controller:

```
 $scope.filterDocuments = function (row) {
          var dateCompare = $filter('date')(row.FilingDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy');

          if (dateCompare >= $scope.dateLimit) {
              if ($scope.query === '' || $scope.query === undefined) {
                  return true;
              } else if (angular.lowercase(row.Description).indexOf($scope.query) !== -1) {
                  return true;
              } else {
                  return false;
              }
          } else {
              return false;
          }
      };
```

This function is used to filter the data during an ng-repeat. What happens is the date comparision is acting like a string comparision. I have tried changing the code to this:

```
 $scope.filterDocuments = function (row) {
          var dateCompare = $filter('date')(row.FilingDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy');

          if (dateCompare.getTime() >= $scope.dateLimit.getTime()) {
              if ($scope.query === '' || $scope.query === undefined) {
                  return true;
              } else if (angular.lowercase(row.Description).indexOf($scope.query) !== -1) {
                  return true;
              } else {
                  return false;
              }
          } else {
              return false;
          }
      };
```

And that fails worse!

How to fix this so that the date comparision works and I can filter based upon the dates?

Comment: This line is unclear  `var dateCompare = $filter('date')(row.FilingDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy');` What is the type of `dateCompare`. Did you debug the code and check the values/types of `dateCompare` and `$scope.dateLimit`?

Comment: `$filter('date')` return formatted string

Comment: If it returns a string, why is the OP complaining about string comparison? It's doing what they asked it to do? OP, you are not explaining well what the problem is, what is the input you are using and exactly how is it failing?

Comment: @JuanMendes, i think OP expect date object instead :-) because it try `getTime()`

Comment: @Grundy Then the OP should have seen an error on the console, I have little patience for someone who doesn't even check the console :) I know, I can be a jerk when I don't see enough effort.

Comment: you can still use filter with other format:  `var dateCompare = $filter('date')(row.FilingDate, 'yyyyMMdd');` and for _dateLimit_ also, in this case comparing by string same as comaring date

Comment: If both `row.FillingDate` and `$scope.dateLimit` are Date objects then just compare them directly without running one through the filter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer on another thread (can't find it now). I am using the following function:

```
function stringToDate(_date, _format, _delimiter) {
    var formatLowerCase = _format.toLowerCase();
    var formatItems = formatLowerCase.split(_delimiter);
    var dateItems = _date.split(_delimiter);
    var monthIndex = formatItems.indexOf("mm");
    var dayIndex = formatItems.indexOf("dd");
    var yearIndex = formatItems.indexOf("yyyy");
    var month = parseInt(dateItems[monthIndex]);
    month -= 1;
    var formatedDate = new Date(dateItems[yearIndex], month, dateItems[dayIndex]);
    return formatedDate;
}
```

This takes a date string and returns a formatted date. I then use that to do the comparision:

```
if (stringToDate(dateCompare, 'mm/did/yyyy', '/') >= stringToDate($scope.dateLimit, 'mm/did/yyyy', '/')) {
```

It works like a charm :)

Comment: Note that you are now taking a date, changing it to a string with `filter("date")`, and then parsing the string as a Date for comparison. Not especially efficient.

Comment: your code not working: you expect 3 params, but pass just one, so when you try execute line: `var formatLowerCase = _format.toLowerCase();` you get exception

Comment: I fixed the code to reflect the proper syntax. My bad. @MikeMcCaughan I didn't change my question for obvious reasons, but I have refactored the code to handle that issue at the same time I implemented the new function, but thank you for pointing it out! :)